# Struggling with the concept of relating g(n) to f(n)- is my reasoning correct for these examples?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

I need to determine the relationship of the following functions and prove them. I don't think I fully understand their relationship and how to approach this in general. Is my reasoning correct for them?

1. `=5+1, =10+30` f=O(g) because with constant c=2 and n=2, 5n+2<=c*10n+30, aka 12<=70
2. `=^n, =2^n` f(n)<g(n) because there isn't a set of c and n that make g>n

Comment: Notice that both *f=O(g)* and *g=O(f)* are true.

Comment: For both functions? Can you explain how you get to that conclusion? I'm really lost on this.

Comment: Sorry, for case 1 only

Comment: OK, can you explain how you came to that conclusion?

Comment: They belong to the same complexity class of functions, *O(n)*. Both are linear. Their asymptotic growth is the same. *f = ϴ(g)*. Many ways to say it. You can find your constants both ways - try it. In case 2, it works only one way because they belong to different complexity classes.

Comment: I'm always annoyed when teachers, even professors, present this as "f *equals* O(g)" rather than "f *in* O(g)". it's a set of functions. there is no equality of a function to a set of functions. -- this is compsci, not programming. ask such stuff on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

One approach that you can take is to extend your functions f and g to the set of real numbers, take the derivative of both f and g and compare the derivatives. If the derivative of both functions are always bigger than zero after a certain point and g' > f' after a certain point, you can guarantee that f = O(g). This criteria is enough to determine that f = O(g) in your first example and g = O(f) in your second example.